# How to make http-request from Flask app to external service and wait for callback

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have a Flask-based app which receives some data and requests to few external services based on this data.
One of external services sends request to specifed url after it has finished process (kinda callback).
The issue is about how to stop the processing of Flask app and wait until request to this specified url and then continue Flask's flow.

i have tried to stop it with loop/flag:

```
    while CALLBACK_FLAG:
        print(f'still waiting for callback')
        time.sleep(10)
```

and to create separated endpoint for callback `/callback_url/` which changes CALLBACK_FLAG after receive request, but it doesn't work.

So could you describe any conceptions/libs which could help to implement this concept with using Flask?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you calling the external services?

Comment: @WytammaWirth  i'm using requests lib, for example:response = requests.get(url=data_for_request['url'],
                                        params=data_for_request['params'],
                                        headers=data_for_request['headers'],
                                        data=data_for_request['data']
                                        )